# Single Thread ExecutorService with PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executorservice

I am looking to implement the following API for a custom `Executor`:

```
public interface PriorityExecutor extends ExecutorService {
    <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task, int priority);
}
```

The idea behind this being that `PriorityExecutor` will receive `Callable` objects with different priorities, and will execute the highest priority items first in a single thread.

The following class is used as a wrapper for the Callable and priority:

```
class PriorityFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T> {
    private int priority;

    PriorityFutureTask(Callable<T> callable, int priority) {
        super(callable);
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

And the following comparator is given to the PriorityBlockingQueue:

```
private class PriorityFutureTaskComparator<T extends PriorityFutureTask> implements Comparator<T> {
        @Override
        public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
            return t2.getPriority() - t1.getPriority();
        }
    }
```

So far, the `PriorityBlockingQueue` behaves as expected when items are added.

If I didn't care about the result of the Future objects returned by submit, it would be very easy to have a single thread that processes the highest priority item from the queue until there are none left.

However, I haven't figured out how to execute the `PriorityFutureTasks` in `PriorityExecutor` in such a way that the priorities are taken into account, and the caller can get the result from the Future returned by `submit()`

Comment: Is the question about how to create and update `Future`s? *Two asides: first I'd set the `priority` field to `final`, second `int`s should be compared with `Integer.compare()` to avoid nasty surprises caused by overflow.*

Comment: The question is about how to run them. Say I submit tasks with the following priorities, in the following order: 1 1 5 1 1
I would like the running order to be 5 1 1 1 1
And when I submit the tasks using submit(Callable, priority) I would like this method to return a Future where I can call get() to retrieve the result

Comment: In that case the simplest solution is to just instantiate a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with core pool size of 1, max pool size of 1 and your priority blocking queue. Unless you specifically want to learn how to write your custom `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Cool, that's what I'm doing at the moment. It works OK when I submit tasks (I call execute(task);) in the submit method). However if I call get() on the Futures, the program waits until each task is finished to submit the next one. They get executed in calling order, not by priority.

Comment: @liarspocker probably you submit the task and wait for the execution, so that the `PriorityQueue` never get multiple entries.